# sending a form via ajax return no method error (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Bibliography (biblio) and a model Author (auteur).

In the form for adding new biography, I have a pop-up that shows a form for adding an Author.

This is in my biblio_controller:

```
@aut = Auteur.new
```

the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @aut, url: administration_auteurs_creer_path, remote: true do |f| %>
```

The form sends these params to the auteurs_controller :

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "auteur"=>{"prenom"=>"Georges", "nom"=>"Espinas", "fonction"=>"", "universite"=>"", "commentaire"=>""}, "commit"=>"Enregistrer"}
```

Auteurs_controller contains:

```
def create
    @auteur = Auteur.new(params_auteur)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @auteur.save
            format.html{}
            format.js{}
            format.json{
                render json: @auteur, status: :created, location: administration_nouveau_biblio_path
            }
        else
            format.html{ render action: "new"}
            format.json{ render json: @auteur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
        end
    end
end


private
    def params_auteur
        params.require(:auteur).permit(:prenom, :nom, :fonction, :universite, :commentaire)
    end
```

EDIT:

This is my auteur model:

```
class Auteur < ApplicationRecord

    has_and_belongs_to_many :biblios

    validates :auteur, presence: true

    def nom_complet
        prenom + " " + nom
    end

    def self.cherche_in_aut(nom)
        where('nom LIKE ?', "%#{nom}%").pluck(:id)
    end

end
```

I get this error message:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method `auteur' for #<Auteur:0x007ff92e116e88>):
app/controllers/administration/auteurs_controller.rb:17:in `block in create'
app/controllers/administration/auteurs_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

line 17 is this: `@auteur.save`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the condition of the if statement onto the same line. (if @auteur.save should be on one line, not two.)

Edit:

I'm guessing from your error message that auteur isn't a column in the auteurs table. If it's not in your schema remove the `validates :auteur` line and it should work.

Comment: That's true. Corrected it. But still having the same error.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the auteur model?

Comment: Updated my answer!